# RRule not setting correct time if dtstart is set

Tags: reactjs, rrule

I try to make an rrule instance and then set the start date/time (dtstart) but the events get the wrong time.

1. I initialize a rrule instance with a basis rrule string:
   `RRULE:FREQ=WEEKLY;INTERVAL=1;WKST=MO;COUNT=20`
2. I set the dtstart date in the `rrule.options` like so:
   `rrule.options.dtstart = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 1, 4, 12, 30, 0))`
3. I console.log `rrule.all()` to see the generated events. All events now have the **current** time instead of the time set via dtstart. It **should** show 12:30 instead

I made this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y05ny6jl51) demonstrating the problem.

Now, when I do exactly the same in [rrule.js demo page](http://jakubroztocil.github.io/rrule/#/rfc/DTSTART:20190114T123000Z), I get correct results.
On this demo page, do the following to see what I mean:
[image]

These are the results:

[image]

As you can see, time of the events is set correctly!

Any advice appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Found the answer:

If you set `distart` explicitly in the constructor, then the problem is solved.

Compare these examples:

Example one: gives correct results:

```
const rrule = new RRule({
  freq: RRule.WEEKLY, 
  interval: 1, 
  wkst: RRule.MO, 
  count: 20,
  dtstart: new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 1, 4, 12, 30, 0))})
```

Example two: gives wrong results

```
const rrule = new RRule({
  freq: RRule.WEEKLY, 
  interval: 1, 
  wkst: RRule.MO, 
  count: 20})
rrule.options.dtstart = new Date(Date.UTC(2019, 1, 4, 14, 30, 0));
```

To me, this looks a bit counter intuitive because setting dtstart should always give the same result whether you set it in the constructor or set it afterwards.

Comment: Thank you, you saved me from a really big rabbit hole i was falling in.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, That should be documented somewhere.

Comment: I think it is because `byhour`, `byminute` and `bysecond` get set to the current time in the constructor. So these have to be changed as well.